# MFMailCompose Freezes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have an app written and on the App Store that has fully functioning forms where users enter information, click submit and this info is loaded into a blank e-Mail, I am back working on this app now and none of my forms work anymore, the e-Mail tries to load and then crashes the app giving the error 'Thread 1: signal SIGBART' in the class line of the AppDelegate, nothing has been changed in the code i have written, as shown below:

```
let To = ["danielpetters@arbus.co.uk"]
    let Title = "This is the subject..."
    let Body = "This is the body..."

    let mc : MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()

    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self

    mc.setToRecipients(To)
    mc.setSubject(Title)
    mc.setMessageBody(Body, isHTML: false)


    self.presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)

  }
```

I have the 'MessageUI' imported and the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate assigned to the class and have even tried re-writing the whole .swift file for the page but had no success. I'm not sure whether this has been caused by an update to Swift or something but any help on this would be appreciated massively!!

Comment: are you trying to use it on simulator?

Comment: nah i've tried running it on my device too.

Comment: and what line is called before SIGBART?

Comment: What do you mean mate?

Comment: you need to see line that breaks your app, where is the line that make your app crash?

Comment: I just set a breakpoint before the first 'let' statement and ran it, i kept stepping in until it threw the SIGBART error at 'self.presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)'

Comment: i've just copied and pasted your code, everything is ok, clean project restart xcode or run that on different machine

Comment: I've got it sorted mate cheers, it turns out that since i got my phone back from repair there was no e-Mail account on it and that was the issue! Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should put a condition to check whether the mail account is setup or not. If there is a mail account then you should proceed further else display a message that "No mail account found."